Is the current reference direction just a reference?
I am now learning about electrical circuits from scratch. Regarding the current reference direction, may I ask if it is just a reference right and the actual direction should be based on whether the current is positive or negative?
For example, in the image below:

The current's reference direction and voltage's reference polarity are given as shown in the image. But it also gives the actual value of the voltage and current, and the current's value is negative, so this means that the actual current direction should be the opposite of what the image shows, right? So, I am just wondering why cannot this image show the correct direction at first.

Without further information your question cannot be satisfactorily answered.  What is component $C$? Where did this diagram come from? in the text the diagram came from is there a reference to the sign convention used?

Component C is just an electrical element. In the text, there is no convention mentioned. The book I am using is electrical engineering: principles and Applications seventh edition. The book has some definitions of the reference direction in the previous chapters. But I guess this concept may be general so I don't include the book's definition/convention.

The convention used in your textbook is called the passive sign convention / associated variables convention and the component $C$ shown in the diagram could be a discharging battery.
I have slightly changed the diagram you provided.

$+,\,-,\,v_{\rm c},\,i_{\rm c}$ and $\rightarrow$ are all labels with the current direction label $\rightarrow$ always pointing at the node labelled $+$.
$v_{\rm c}$ is the voltage of the node labelled $+$ ($b$ in the diagram) relative to the voltage of the node labelled $-$ ($a$ in the diagram).
In this example the potential of node $b$ is $12\,\rm V$ higher than the potential of node $a$.
$i_{\rm c}$ is the current taking the current direction label, $\rightarrow$, as positive.
In this example a current of $3 \,\rm A$ is flowing in the opposite direction to the current direction arrow, ie from node $a$ to node $b$.
Furthermore when using this convention if the power $v_{\rm c}\,i_{\rm c}$ is positive it means that the component is a consumer (sink) of electrical power and an example would be a resistor.
As the power $v_{\rm c}\,i_{\rm c}\, (= 12\times (-3) = -36 \,W)$ is negative it means that the component is a source of electrical power and an example would be a discharging battery.
If $i_{\rm c}$ had been $+3\,\rm A$, with the current flowing from node $b$ to node $a$, the power, $v_{\rm c}\,i_{\rm c}\, (= 12\times (+3) = +36 \,W)$, would be positive  indicating that the component is a sink of electrical power and so might be a battery which was being recharged.

Yeah, this image is a passive reference configuration as stated in the textbook. So, the current reference is given in order to show that this is a passive reference configuration, and the reason why the Ic is negative is to show that this is a discharging battery?

It could be due to the asymmetry between electrons and positive charge carriers.
While a reference could be in any direction, the ease of transporting electrons in a circuit could lead to a preference for defining the flow of current in the same direction electrons travel in the circuit.
Additionally, I seem to recall a historical reason whereby a standard direction of reference was established. Again, the convention could be inverted, but through popular usage became a standard (if I recall correctly). I believe this standard happened to be in the direction opposite to the flow of electrons.
This is a quick note, someone else may be able to provide more detail, including references.
